# C++ Inheritance and virtual keyword on base_class with derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

Sorry maybe I should rewrite my question in a better way.

I've a base class name `ABC` that have function name.

```
void saysez(ostream &os) const // this is NOT virtual!!
            { os << sez; }
```

and derived class name `DEF` that also have function name

```
void saysez(ostream &os) const { os << extra << " ";
                         scary::saysez(os);
```

So as we can see from the above code both having same signature.

In my understanding if there is no `virtual` keyword specified it should use the base class function but in my walkthrough practice the output it turned out that it is using the derived's function.

So I'm wondering why it is used the derived's function over base's function?

Below is the call from `int main`

```
     w.saysez(cout);  cout << '\n';
```

`w` is the object from derived class.

Below is the link to the snipped code with an output

http://codepad.org/Pz5jwMVP

Comment: Please format your code properly.  It's currently horrible.

Comment: Sorry I'm going to reformat them now.

Comment: `I have a question on the last line of the output` - Then you should provide the relevant code for that alone, since the rest is just noise.

Comment: @amit I will remove if those will not really help anyway?

Comment: @Ali: You should provide the minimum compileable code that describes the issue at hand - that will probably get you more accurate and better answers.

Comment: @amit Thank you for your suggestion I will keep that in mind. The only reason I provided the whole codes because some people give me -1 because the codes were missing and they don't understand what I really want.

Sorry once again.

Comment: @Ali: No need to sorry, I am commenting in order to help you improve your questions. As I said, the code snap should be minimal compleable code - I doubt you are likely to get `-1` if it fits both these criteria.

Comment: Ah... as I've said several times already, please see my answer and also take a look at ds1848's link. Also, it's good that you've updated your question to make it easier to understand, but a compilable example is generally always better, not to mention that you're still using `scary` to qualify a function call when you're now referring to your classes as `ABC` and `DEF`. Asking a question well takes practice, so hopefully this one has given you some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, please correct me if I don't understand your question correctly.

We use inheritance for many reasons and one of them is to code efficiently. For example, in your case,

you want to inherit the class scary which means you want to have the functionality of class scary in the derived classes. You can copy all of the member functions in the based class to have the same functionality as the based calls, but what if you decide to change something in one of the functions? you have to change all of them. so it is inefficient way of coding.

Now in you class, you asking why is object w in this line `w.saysez(cout);  cout << '\n';` because both class scary and class which have the same member function, the `w` should look in its class first for a match, if it doesn't find it, it will then look in the based class. Therefore, your object is calling the `saysez` member function in its class.

hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you so much now I understand why it is using the saysez from witch instead.

So what if there is a virtual keyword in base will it still used the one from the derived?

Comment: Again, this doesn't explain why the `witch` object chooses the overridden member function when it's not declared as `virtual`. Please see ds1848's [link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr139.htm) and [mine](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.8) for a proper understanding of what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

I have a hard time understanding your question.  The virtual keyword seems irrelevant to this problem.  Your class witch has a member function void saysez(ostream&) and when you create an instance of this class and call w.saysez, the compiler matches the definition of saysez it found in your implementation of witch.

The virtual keyword really doesn't matter here.  If don't want to see the 'Double Double' part, then cast w to a scary:

```
((scary*)&w)->saysez(cout)
```

and you won't see the 'Double Double' part printed out.

Please see [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr139.htm) or just about any other site that discusses the virtual keyword for more information.

Comment: I've changed my question and hope that is going to make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a smaller sample you could have posted that still demonstrates your issue:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <cstring>

class scary {
    char is[31];
    char sez[31];
public:
    scary() {
        strcpy(is, "Creep");
        strcpy(sez, "boooo");
    }
    scary(const char i[], const char s[])
    {
        strcpy(is, i); strcpy(sez, s);
    }
    virtual void sayis(ostream &os) const { os << is; }
    void saysez(ostream &os) const // this is NOT virtual!!
        { os << sez; }
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const scary &x) {
    x.saysez(os);
    os << ", said the ";
    x.sayis(os);
    return os;
}

class ghost: public scary {
public:
    ghost():scary("Ghost", "Boo!")
    {
    }
};

class witch: public scary {
    char extra[31];
public:
    witch(): scary("Witch", "Toil and Trouble") {
        strcpy(extra, "Double, Double");
    }
    void saysez(ostream &os) const {
        os << extra << " ";
        scary::saysez(os);
    }
};

int main() {
    scary s; 
    ghost g; 
    witch w;
    cout << s << '\n' << g << '\n' << w << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
boooo, said the Creep
Boo!, said the Ghost
Toil and Trouble, said the Witch
```

In `witch`'s constructor, you set the `sez` array to `"Toil and Trouble"` and then in `saysez` declared in `witch` you print out `extra` and call `scary`'s `saysez` function which prints out `sez`. This happens because it is possible (but not encouraged) to [override non-virtual member functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.8).

Comment: Well my question is that if there was no `virtual` keyword on that function then why it is used the one from derived but not from the base class?.

I though the rules is that if there is no virtual keyword specified it should use the one from the base not from the derived class?

Comment: Sorry, I did update my answer a few times and you might not have seen [this link](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.8) which explains that overriding a non-virtual member function is legal but should be avoided. The overridden member function will be called on the static type of the object.

Comment: I've changed my question if you could take a look at it again and see if it was the same what you thought at the first place.

Sorry again!

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that w is declared as an element of type witch, so of course it is going to call witch::saysez(). If, though, you did:

```
scary* w2 = new witch();
w2->saysez(cout);
```

...then you should see the scary::saysez() behavior.

It looks like you have misunderstood how non-virtual functions work with inherited classes. Both virtual and non-virtual functions can be overridden. On an object of class Foo, if you call Foo::MyNonVirtualFn(), it will just execute the body of Foo::MyNonVirtualFn(). If Foo has a superclass that implements MyNonVirtualFn(), or if the object it's being called on is actually an instance of a subclass of Foo that overrides MyNonVirtualFn() -- none of that matters. If the function call is to Foo::MyNonVirtualFn(), then that is the version of the function that runs. (If you aren't explicit about what version of MyNonVirtualFn() you're calling it infers it from the type that you're calling it with -- for pointer or reference types this might not be exactly the same as the type of the object.)

Virtual functions are different in that if you call Foo::MyVirtualFn() on an object it will *check to see if the object is an instance of a subclass of Foo that has overridden MyVirtualFn()*. So, for instance:

```
Base* base = new Base();
Derived* derived = new Derived();
Base* derived_as_base = derived;

base->MyNonVirtualFn();  // Calls Base::MyNonVirtualFn().
derived->MyNonVirtualFn();  // Calls Derived::MyNonVirtualFn().
derived_as_base->MyNonVirtualFn();  // Calls Base::MyNonVirtualFn() because it's called on a Base*.

base->MyVirtualFn();  // Calls Base::MyNonVirtualFn().
derived->MyVirtualFn();  // Calls Derived::MyNonVirtualFn().
derived_as_base->MyVirtualFn();  // Calls Derived::MyNonVirtualFn() because it uses a lookup table.
```

Comment: Well my question is that if there was no `virtual` keyword on that function then why it is used the one from derived but not from the base class?.

I though the rules is that if there is no virtual keyword specified it should use the one from the base not from the derived class?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question - if I were a beginner I'd be more confused after having read it, especially since the code you posted would appear to exhibit polymorphic behaviour and instead exhibits early binding. Please at least mention why this happens.

Comment: Yes, sorry -- didn't add much detail at first because I wasn't 100% sure from his question if I'd understood exactly what his misunderstanding was, now that I know it I've responded in much greater detail.